# Saving XML file “on the fly” in c#

Tags: c#, xml, file, save

I work on an app where user can type in some text. Text is saved to XML file, I try to make the file save “on the fly” as user is typing so it saves instantly. However if data is typed quick, I get an error of “file currently in use”. How to overcome this issue?

Comment: Can you please show your code so we can help?

Comment: The issue is the file isn't done saving before the next letter is typed and it tries to save the file again. Seems like a lot of unnecessary processing power to save the file over and over on each letter... It might be better to save every X number of seconds if the text has changed.

Comment: Yes, I know why it is happening but trying to find some way around it. Perhaps timer is an option.

Comment: IO takes time. More time then your code does. Use a queue system for your changes instead.

Comment: It sounds like you are triggering a save on literally every keystroke. That is excessive. You should do something like trigger a save after there haven't been any keystrokes for X seconds. However, in order for this to be a valid question on StackOverflow, you need to include a [mcve] and show your attempt at solving the problem. Take a look at [ask].

Comment: Are you opening the file every time you add data or are you keeping the file open?  What method are you using to write xml.  Well formed XML has only one node at root.  So if you are writing partial xml data without closing tags you can get issues depending on the method you are using to save file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you are trying to write a file while the previous write operation is incomplete and the file is still open for write.

Now, if you absolutely must make a write on every character change - I would put in a queue in place, so when XML content is changed - instead of writing to a file right away - agg a message to a queue. Then have the code that monitors that queue and only writes the next chnage once the previous write has finished.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put a flag to control if the file is already open or not. If this is open, you keep the text and don't write on XML, but if it is not you just write.

This is a concurrency problem, you can acess the website: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/concurrency-in-c/9781491906675/ch01.html to get more options.